# How to find a $K_4$ on $4$-cube?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, euclidean-geometry

Let $Q$ be a $4$-cube of length $2\times 2\times 2\times 1$. In [this website](http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/hypercube.htm)
for a $4$-cube of length $1\times 1\times 1\times 1$ explained that

> If you add the coordinates of one point, you get the sums $0,1,2,3,$ or $4$. The sums $0$ and $4$ belong to opposite corners. They are ending points of a diagonal (green). If you join the points with the sums $1$ or $3$, you get two tetrahedra (red).
> If you join the points with the sum $2$, you get an octohedron (blue).
> If you write $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=a$ and substitute all numbers between $0$ and $4$ with $a$, you find another body as a section to every value.
> The section is perpendicular to the diagonal from $(0,0,0,0)$ to $(1,1,1,1)$.

Is there a similar way to find a complete equal-side graph $K_4$ of length $2\sqrt{2}$ on $Q$?

Any suggestions would be appreciate.

Comment: Google image search for inscribed tetrahedron in cube: https://www.google.com/search?q=inscribeded+tetrahedron+in+cube&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihjKLst8XWAhVj4oMKHYciBhwQsAQIOw&biw=1173&bih=818

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. similar this, how to prove a complete equal-side graph $K_8$ of length $4$ on $8$-cube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular tetrahedron $K_4$ with edge lengths $2\sqrt{2}$ can be found in usual three-dimensional cube $\{0,2\}^3$ as the set of vertices $(0,0,0), (2,2,0), (2,0,2), (0,2,2)$. These are exactly the vertices of the cube with sum of all coordinates equal to $0$ modulo $4$.